# Using Nintendo copyrighted Pictures in a booklet

Tags: copyright, austria

Me and a colleague of mine are planning to do a Pokèmon Go guide - but we are held off because all of the screenshots/graphics would of course be copyrighted material.
A few days ago i saw such a guide booklet clearly containing copyrighted graphics.
My question as a law noob is now: Am i allowed to use such copyrighted content if the major part of my product (such as textual information) comes from me?

Comment: You could ask for permission from Nintendo as "fair use". If they agree then you have permission.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The booklet you saw is either licences by Nintendo or illegal.